# Android: Difference between ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED and ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package

I found 2 similar broadcast event `ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` and `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`. But what is there use cases differences? What is the real differences between them if I want to receive a broadcast event when a package has been un-installed?

Pleas Note: I'm new on android Development and learning day by day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the highlight code its the difference between both of it...

ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED -: Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.

ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED - : Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been completely removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. This is like ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED, **but only set when EXTRA_DATA_REMOVED is true and EXTRA_REPLACING is false of that broadcast.**

Comment: So can we safely say that ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED == uninstall?

Comment: Yes you can use ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED == uninstall

Answer (score 2):

as android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm states:

> This class listens for the {@code PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED} intent rather than
>   {@code PACKAGE_REMOVED} as {@code PACKAGE_REMOVED} is triggered on re-installation of the same package, where {@code PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED} is triggered only when an application is completely uninstalled.

so, for completely uninstall, we only need PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED.
PACKAGE_REMOVED triggers even re-installation.

however based on test, PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED does not trigger everytime for some reason, I think its because the package unintalled doesnt have any extradata. need more test to prove this.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/lollipop-dev/src/com/android/server/telecom/PhoneAccountBroadcastReceiver.java